# How to pass the Appstore review for the app like Uber?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My company made an app like Grab, Uber: Allow user books a bike/car.

But the problem is: Currently the iOS app for User is ready to publish, but the iOS app for Driver is under development. We want to publish the app for User first, and the app for Driver will be published later. We also have the User app and Driver app for Android, and both for Android is ready to publish.

So, I have a question:
If I submit User app to Appstore, would Apple reject the app? If yes, are there any ways to pass the review?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to get this question answered. If you app complies with https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ it's fine and it doesn't matter if your iOS driver app is not ready (yet).

Comment: no, apple will not reject the app. i have already uploaded user app and its approved. later on upload driver app.